# How to add different comments \begin{comment} , \begin{comment2},

Tags: comments

How can I add several different comments ?

```
\begin{comment} 
something
\end{comment} 

\begin{comment2} 
something2
\end{comment2}
```

Comment: Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en ?

Comment: What makes comments "different"? They are ignored by TeX, what more do you want/need?

Comment: What is the use case for this? Are you talking of comments that are typeset in a certain way or of comments that are just in the code and not typeset at all? If the former: How should these comments look like when printed? If the latter ... well, Ingmar already asked this: Why the need for different environments? Please add some more information to help us understand your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own comment environments in using the `\newenvironment` command. Have a look:

```
\\newenvironment{comment2}
{\\par\\color{blue}\\textbf{Comment:} \\itshape}
{\\par}

\\begin{comment2}
something2
\\end{comment2}
```

If you provide us with a minimal working example, we can try to focus the answer on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: If it solves your concern, please, accept the answer so it could be marked as resolved.